# How to fix 'TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sender''

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am trying to create a django model instance with a django-rest-framework serializer ModelSerializer class. This is my Serializer code:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['sender', 'chat_room', 'content', 'sending_date']
```

and this is my view when I try to make a model instance out of it:

```
class SendMessage(APIView):
authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

def post(self, request):
    try:
        message_type = request.data['message_type']

        if message_type == ('text' or 'image' or 'audio'):

            if message_type == 'text':

                message_serializer = MessageSerializer(sender=request.user, chat_room=ChatRoom.objects.get(
                    id=request.data['chat_room_id']), content=MessageContent(text=request.data['text']))
                message = Message(message_serializer.data)

            elif message_type == 'image':
                message = MessageSerializer(sender=request.user.id, chat_room=request.data['chat_room_id'],
                                            content=MessageContent(image=request.FILES['image']))

            elif message_type == 'audio':
                message = MessageSerializer(sender=request.user.id, chat_room=request.data['chat_room_id'],
                                            content=MessageContent(image=request.FILES['image']))

            if message.chat_room.users.all().filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
                message.save()

                if message_type == 'image':
                    resize_photo(message.content.image, MessageContent.image_width, MessageContent.image_height)

                if message_type == 'audio':
                    if (not message.content.name.lower().endswith('mp4')) and os.get_size(message.content) > 25000:
                        message.delete()
                        raise FileSourceError

                message.save()
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    except KeyError or FileSourceError:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is my message model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    chat_room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, related_name='chat_room', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    content = models.OneToOneField(MessageContent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    is_read_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="is_read_by")

    sending_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('sending_date',)
```

However, when I run this code, I get

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sender'

If I delete the sender argument I get

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chat_room'

and so on. I checked if my ModelSerializer was making the right serializer fields with

`print(repr(MessageSerializer()))`

in the django python shell, and I got

```
MessageSerializer():
    sender = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    chat_room = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ChatRoom.objects.all())
    content = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=MessageContent.objects.all(), validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Message.objects.all())>])
    sending_date = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
```

which means that my serializer has these fields (sender, chat_room, etc.)
Why do I get this error and how do I fix this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please, share the whole code for your view and your model.

Comment: @HuLuViCa Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supposed to pass a `Message` model instance to `MessageSerializer` or a `dict` containing data with the keys specified in `fields`.

In case you want to pass a `dict`, pass the `dict` to `data` keyword.

```
message_dict = {'sender': request.user, 'chat_room': ChatRoom.objects.get(id=request.data['chat_room_id']), 'content': MessageContent(text=request.data['text'])}
message_serializer = MessageSerializer(data=message_dict)

if message_serializer.is_valid():
    message_serializer.save()
```

Make sure you have `create` method implemented in your `MessageSerializer`.

Comment: I tried to give the __init__ function a dict instead of multiple kargs and I still got TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sender'

Comment: Follow instructions [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances).

Comment: I gtg to sleep now but ill check that tomorrow thank you

Comment: @VincentQuirion If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know.

Comment: you are most welcome. also if the answer was helpful, it's good to upvote to help someone with similar problem in future. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the **model.py** file in one of the class attributes change

**`identification = models.IntegerField()`**

In the **model.py** file in one of the class attributes change

```
identification = models.IntegerField ()
```

Do not leave anything inside the parentheses, then in the console check with the following command

```
python manage.py check application_name
```